# ¿las consultas en firebase devuelven un callback de error?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Los **Query** en **firebase** devuelven alguna función de error, estoy haciendo una consulta, pero no siempre encontrara algo, ¿cómo se si es null?

```
  vm.settlements.child('liqui')
                .orderByChild("rut")
                .equalTo(employee.rut)
                .on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                    $scope.keyExist = snapshot.val();
                    $scope.keyExistID = snapshot.key;
                });
```

Comment: Puedes leer **[la doc, además en castellano](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)**: _La función de callback recibe un DataSnapshot, que es una instantánea de los datos. Una instantánea es una imagen de los datos en una referencia particular de base de datos en un momento especifico. Si se llama a val() / getValue() en una instantánea, se obtendrá la representación de los datos como objeto de JavaScript. **Si no existen datos en la ubicación de la referencia, el valor de la instantánea será null**._ Puedes preguntar si la instantánea (snapshot) es `null`.

Comment: @A.Cedano ahora entiemdo mas, pero pasa que si no encuentra nada, no entra en .on() solo llega hasta .equalTo() y ahi no me alcanza a saber si es null o no

Answer (score 0):

Claro solo tienes que añadirla al método **on**:

```
vm.settlements.child('liqui')
                .orderByChild("rut")
                .equalTo(employee.rut)
                .on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                    $scope.keyExist = snapshot.val();
                    $scope.keyExistID = snapshot.key;
                }, function(error){
                    console.log(Error, error);
                });
```